# How do you say "audio (sound track)"?

Tags: contemporary-latin

I was trying to say to a friend of mine "We need to speak in Latin through audio" and I just noticed I have no idea the appropriate word for "audio" in Latin. And it doesn't help the fact that the word "audio" is Latin for "I hear" lol. Is there a word already invented to be used in Latin for the modern concept of "audio" (as in an audio file you send to someone)? If so, how does one go about saying it? Is there any dictionary of Living Latin you guys go through to find words and expressions for our modern needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about *sonus*, literally "sound", or *vox*, literally "voice", depending on context?

In other words, I would say "we need to converse by *voice*" (*voce*), or "I'm sending an image file and a *sound* file" (*sonī*). The latter trick, the genitive of the noun for "a sound", is often used in Modern Greek (*ήχου*), which seems like a good precedent.

Comment: That sounds like a perfect alternative! Thank you

Comment: @VictorBC: You may accept this answer (now or later, if you want to wait for other suggestions) by clicking on the check mark just below the vote buttons of it. This rewards the poster of the answer most useful to you, and makes it evident that your query has been resolved. Welcome on board, stick around!

Comment: Gratias tibi ago! I did so now.